# File Upload on Swagger Controller Interface

Tags: java, swagger

I'm creating an API micro-service that provides file storage with AWS. I'm putting together the Swagger and Controller, and we need to be able to allow users to upload a file on the Swagger. The problem is our controller is set up as an interface instead of a class, and solutions from Google/SO aren't making the cut to be able to work with interfaces. To clarify, I don't need to manipulate the file at all, just take it in. Our internal implementation methods will take then send it off to S3.

This is using Java 11, AWS S3, Spring Boot, and Swagger 2. I've tried using `@ApiParam` and `@FormDataParam` inside the method `createFile`, but I've gotten two different **errors:**

1. method must be abstract
2. annotations are not allowed here.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = {"v3/registration/documents", "v4/registration/documents"})
@RestController
@Api(
    value = "file-storage",
    description = "File storage service",
    tags = {"file-storage"})
public interface FileController {
  @PostMapping(
      value = "/{salesPlanAff}",
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
      consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
  @ApiOperation(value = "Upload a file")
  @ApiResponses(
      value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = FileResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")
      })
  void createFile(
      @PathVariable(required = true, name = "webSessionId") String webSessionId,
      @PathVariable(required = false, name = "salesPlanAff") String salesPlanAff);
```

What I expected is to have a button on my swagger page allowing file upload, didn't quite expect this much difficulty in adding file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I have a FileUpload in my swagger page and it works like a charm. The only difference from your is that I am not doing it on an interface...

```java
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
     ...
@ApiOperation(value = "Analyse the identifiers in the file")
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public AnalysisResult getPostFile( @ApiParam(name = "file", value = "The file")
                                   @RequestPart MultipartFile file,
                                   HttpServletRequest r) {
    UserData ud = controller.getUserData(file);
    return controller.analyse(ud, r, file.getOriginalFilename());
    }
```

I trimmed off a little bit this code, but you can find a the original one in our [repository](https://github.com/reactome/analysis-service/blob/master/src/main/java/org/reactome/server/analysis/service/controller/IdentifiersController.java)

Also, working version of this code can be executed tested [here](https://dev.reactome.org/AnalysisService/#/identifiers/getPostFileUsingPOST)

Thanks

Comment: Not a problem with it being a class instead of interface, I've been able to adapt. Question for you, what in your code actually takes in the file? I can't have a method body, only parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the annotations in, part of it stemmed from typos. For anyone interested, here's the solution:

```java
public interface FileController {
  @PostMapping(
      value = "/{salesPlanAff}",
      produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
      consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
  @ApiOperation(value = "Upload a file")
  @ApiResponses(
      value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = FileResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "Created"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")
      })
  void createFile(
      @PathVariable(required = true, name = "webSessionId") String webSessionId,
      @PathVariable(required = false, name = "salesPlanAff") String salesPlanAff,
      @ApiParam(required = true, value = "Document to be uploaded")
      @RequestPart MultipartFile multipartFile,
      @ApiParam(required = true, value = "File Type")
      @QueryParam("documentType") String documentType);
```